# Convert specific node of XML to CSV with R

Tags: r, xml, csv, dataframe

I have XML file structured like this

```
<Item>
    <Tab1>
        <Info1>x<Info1>
        <Info2>y<Info2>
        <Info3>z<Info3>
    </Tab1>
    <Tab2>
        <Info1>foo<Info1>
        <Info2>bar<Info2>
        <Info3>foobar<Info3>
    </Tab2>
</Item>
<Item>
    <Tab1>
        <Info1>x<Info1>
        <Info2>y<Info2>
        <Info3>z<Info3>
    </Tab1>
    <Tab2>
        <Info1>foo<Info1>
        <Info2>bar<Info2>
        <Info3>foobar<Info3>
    </Tab2>
</Item>
```

Using this code

```
file <- "file.xml"
doc <- xmlParse(file, useInternalNodes = TRUE) 
xmldataframe <- xmlToDataFrame(doc)
```

I get dataframe that looks like this

```
Tab1              Tab2
xyz               foobarfoobar
```

But I need only Tab2 info in separate columns. How can I get the following result?

```
Info1 Info2 Info3
foo   bar   foobar
```

Comment: Please identify the package you use to parse the XML.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix up your example XML first (it is currently invalid), but given that you have a vaild XML document, you can use xpath to pull out specific nodes.
 You are usng the XML package it seems (helpful to specify this in a question) so the function `XML::getNodeSet` is what you need:

```
file <- "file.xml"
doc <- XML::xmlParse(file, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
tab2 <- XML::getNodeSet(doc, "//Tab2")
xmldataframe <- XML::xmlToDataFrame(tab2)
```

This gives only the nodes you are looking for.

```
> xmldataframe
  Info1 Info2  Info3
1   foo   bar foobar
2   foo   bar foobar
```